# After reading xml file trying to send mail

Tags: java

I am trying to read the xml file and trying to send the mail.

here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xml>
 <u_incident_task>
 <description>messafe</description>
  <priority>1</priority>
  <number>12345</number>
 <u_task_incident_service_ci>A</u_task_incident_service_ci>
   </u_incident_task>
   <u_incident_task>
  <description>messafe</description>
  <priority>3</priority>
  <number>123456</number>
  <u_task_incident_service_ci>A</u_task_incident_service_ci>
  </u_incident_task>
  </xml>
```

so when ever Priority is 1 i need to send mail. currently my below code is working and able to send.
But when ever Priority is updated from 3 to 1 mail is not able to send. may be the reason i am storing all the number in array since i dont want to send mail repeatedly. so i stored the numbers in array so that i can be sent only once. so while i am storing the numbers if any Priority is updated to 1 mail is not working.

But when record is created with 1 mail i sent but if we updated the existing priority from 3 to 1 it not workin. complete working code is here. can any one help what i missed in logic pls?

complete code here.
Incidentreport2000.java

```
 package com.asn.model;
  import java.awt.Desktop;
  import java.io.BufferedWriter;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileWriter;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Collections;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Map;
  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
  import java.util.Properties;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import com.asn.model.incident200;
import com.asn.model.incident1;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
    import javax.mail.Message;
  import javax.mail.MessagingException;import javax.mail.Session;
 import javax.mail.Transport;
  import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
  import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
 import java.net.InetAddress;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

  import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

 public class incidentreport2000 implements Runnable {
  List<String> number1  =  new ArrayList<String>();
   public incidentreport2000(){

      }



 public void run(){
  for(int i=1;i>0;i++){
try{
    Thread.sleep(9600);
    List<incident1> incident1List = new ArrayList<incident1>();
List<incident200> incident200List = new ArrayList<incident200>();
    FileWriter fw =null;
    BufferedWriter bw=null;
    String Path = "C:\\Users";
    OutputStream out = null;
    URLConnection conn = null;
    InputStream in = null;
InputStream input = null;
    String address ="C:\\Users" ;
      String localFileName = "\\file.xml";
      try {

        File fXmlFile = new File(Path + "\\file.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList incident1NodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("u_incident_task");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < incident1NodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node varNode = incident1NodeList.item(temp);

            if (varNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) varNode;

                NodeList u_task_incident_service_ciList = eElement.getElementsByTagName

       ("u_task_incident_service_ci");
                NodeList varsionList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("priority");
                NodeList numberList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("number");
                  NodeList descriptionList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("description");

           /*     Node u_task_incident_service_ciNode =

     u_task_incident_service_ciList.item(0);
                Node priorityNode = varsionList.item(0);*/
                 Node u_task_incident_service_ciNode =

                u_task_incident_service_ciList.item(0);
                Node priorityNode = varsionList.item(0);
                 Node numberNode = numberList.item(0);
                  Node descriptionNode = descriptionList.item(0);

                if (u_task_incident_service_ciNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
                        && priorityNode.getNodeType() ==

                        Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element u_task_incident_service_ciElement = (Element)

      u_task_incident_service_ciNode;
                    Element priorityElement = (Element) priorityNode;
                    Element numberElement = (Element) numberNode;
                     Element descriptionElement = (Element) descriptionNode;
                    incident1 incident1 = new incident1(
                            u_task_incident_service_ciElement.getTextContent(),

                            priorityElement.getTextContent());
                    incident1List.add(incident1);
                    incident200 incident200 = new incident200(
         u_task_incident_service_ciElement.getTextContent(),
    priorityElement.getTextContent(),numberElement.getTextContent  (),descriptionElement.getTextContent());
                    incident200List.add(incident200);
                }
            }

            // fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            // bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<incident1, Integer> count = new HashMap<incident1, Integer>();
    for (incident1 c : incident1List)
        if (!count.containsKey(c))
            count.put(c, Collections.frequency(incident1List, c));

   List<String> prioritys = getprioritys(count);

    List<String> u_task_incident_service_cis = getu_task_incident_service_cis(count);

   Map<incident200, Integer> count1 = new HashMap<incident200, Integer>();
    for (incident200 c1 : incident200List)
        if (!count1.containsKey(c1))
            count1.put(c1, Collections.frequency(incident200List, c1));
  List<String> number = getnumber(count1);
  List<String> description = getdescription(count1);
   List<String> prioritys1 = getprioritys1(count1);
  List<String> u_task_incident_service_cis1 = getu_task_incident_service_cis1(count1);


    for (String v2 : prioritys1  ) {

    if (v2 =="P1" ){


for (String n2 : number  ) {
    System.out.println(number);
if (!number1.contains(n2)) {
    for (String d : description){
    for (String m3 : u_task_incident_service_cis1){
if (m3 == "A"){

            getCountu_task_incident_service_cis1( m3,prioritys1,n2,d, count1);
    }
    if (m3 == "B"){
                    getCountu_task_incident_service_cis1( m3,prioritys1,n2,d, count1);

    }


    }} number1.add(n2);
    }}

    }}

   }catch(Exception e){}
}



 }

   private static List<String> getu_task_incident_service_cis(Map<incident1, Integer>

    count) {
    List<String> u_task_incident_service_cis = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<incident1, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
        if (!u_task_incident_service_cis.contains(ent.getKey

      ().getu_task_incident_service_ci()))
            u_task_incident_service_cis.add(ent.getKey().getu_task_incident_service_ci

 ());
   System.out.println(u_task_incident_service_cis);
  if(!u_task_incident_service_cis.contains("A"))
            u_task_incident_service_cis.add("A");
    return u_task_incident_service_cis;
    }

 private static List<String> getu_task_incident_service_cis1(Map<incident200, Integer>

count) {
        List<String> u_task_incident_service_cis1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<incident200, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!u_task_incident_service_cis1.contains(ent.getKey

().getu_task_incident_service_ci()))
                u_task_incident_service_cis1.add(ent.getKey().getu_task_incident_service_ci

());
System.out.println(u_task_incident_service_cis1+"NewCIS");
if(!u_task_incident_service_cis1.contains("BIRSD"))
                u_task_incident_service_cis1.add("BIRSD");
        return u_task_incident_service_cis1;
}

  private static String getNumOfu_task_incident_service_cis(String

      u_task_incident_service_ci, List<String> prioritys,
        Map<incident1, Integer>

        count) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


    for (String v : prioritys) {
        Integer cnt = count.get(new incident1(u_task_incident_service_ci, v));
        if (cnt == null) {
            cnt = 0;
        }


    }
   return builder.toString();
}


 private static String getCountu_task_incident_service_cis1(String

 u_task_incident_service_ci, List<String> prioritys1, String number,String description,
            Map<incident200, Integer>

            count1) {
        StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();

   List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String v : prioritys1) {

             if ( v == "P1")     {
     Integer cnt1 = count1.get(new incident200(u_task_incident_service_ci, v,number,description));
                                       if (cnt1 == null) {
                                           cnt1 = 0;
                                       }
                            else
                                       if (cnt1 !=0){
                           cnt1 = 1;

                    if (!ARRAY.contains(number)) {

                         mail1 (u_task_incident_service_ci,v,number,description);

        ARRAY.add(number);

    }
    }}
      else
      if ( v == "P2")    {
      Integer cnt1 = count1.get(new incident200(u_task_incident_service_ci, v,number,description));
      if (cnt1 == null) {
      cnt1 = 0;
      }
      else
      if (cnt1 !=0){

     if (!ARRAY.contains(number)) {
     mail1(u_task_incident_service_ci,v,number,description);
     ARRAY.add(number);
                }}
    }}

return number;

 }
 private static List<String> getprioritys(Map<incident1, Integer> count) {
    List<String> prioritys = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<incident1, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
        if (!prioritys.contains(ent.getKey().getpriority()))
            prioritys.add(ent.getKey().getpriority());

   Collections.sort(prioritys);
    return prioritys;
}

private static List<String> getprioritys1(Map<incident200, Integer> count) {
        List<String> prioritys1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<incident200, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!prioritys1.contains(ent.getKey().getpriority()))
                prioritys1.add(ent.getKey().getpriority());
        ;
//Collections.sort(prioritys);
System.out.println("check1");
        return prioritys1;
    }
     private static List<String> getnumber(Map<incident200, Integer> count) {
        List<String> number = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<incident200, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!number.contains(ent.getKey().getnumber()))
                number.add(ent.getKey().getnumber());


        return number;
    }
    private static List<String> getdescription(Map<incident200, Integer> count) {
        List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<incident200, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!description.contains(ent.getKey().getdescription()))
                description.add(ent.getKey().getdescription());

        return description;
    }




public static void mail1(String Email,String v,String n, String d) {



System.out.println(Email);
System.out.println(v);
        final String username = "mailid";
        final String password = "password";
 //w2011.kpnnl.local
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
//props.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse

("toaddress"));

            message.setSubject("Priority:"+v+": "+n+"Incident has bee raised for the team"+Email);
            message.setText("messager,"
            );

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

incidentreport2000 mrt = new incidentreport2000();



Thread t = new Thread(mrt);

t.start();
String Path = "C:\\Users";
List<String> number1  =  new ArrayList<String>();

}

}
```

incident200.java

```
 package com.asn.model;

 public class incident200 {

private String u_task_incident_service_ci;
private String priority;
private String number;
private String description;

public incident200(String u_task_incident_service_ci, String priority, String number,String description ) {

    super();

   if (u_task_incident_service_ci.equals("A"))
 { String Team= "A";
 this.u_task_incident_service_ci = Team;}
 else
    this.u_task_incident_service_ci = u_task_incident_service_ci;


 if (priority.equals("1"))
 { String priority1 = "P1";
 this.priority = priority1;}
 else
 if (priority.equals("3"))
{ String priority3 = "P3";
 this.priority = priority3;}
  else
 if (priority.equals("4"))
 { String priority4 = "P3";
 this.priority = priority4;}
 else
if (priority.equals("5"))
 { String priority5 = "P3";
 this.priority = priority5;}
 else
 if (priority.equals("2"))
{ String priority2 = "P2";
this.priority = priority2;}
 else
    this.priority = priority;

    this.number = number;
this.description = description;
}
public String getu_task_incident_service_ci() {
    return u_task_incident_service_ci;
}
public void setu_task_incident_service_ci(String u_task_incident_service_ci) {

    this.u_task_incident_service_ci = u_task_incident_service_ci;
}
public String getpriority() {
    return priority;
}
public void setpriority(String priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}
 public String getnumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setnumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
}
 public String getdescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setdescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((u_task_incident_service_ci == null) ? 0 : u_task_incident_service_ci.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((priority == null) ? 0 : priority.hashCode());
     result = prime * result + ((number == null) ? 0 : number.hashCode());
     result = prime * result + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    incident200 other = (incident200) obj;
    if (u_task_incident_service_ci == null) {
        if (other.u_task_incident_service_ci != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!u_task_incident_service_ci.equals(other.u_task_incident_service_ci))
        return false;
    if (priority == null) {
        if (other.priority != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!priority.equals(other.priority))
        return false;

         if (number == null) {
                if (other.number != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!number.equals(other.number))
        return false;
          if (description == null) {
                        if (other.description != null)
                            return false;
                    } else if (!description.equals(other.description))
        return false;
    return true;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("incident99 [u_task_incident_service_ci=");
    builder.append(u_task_incident_service_ci);
    builder.append(", priority1=");
    builder.append(priority);
    builder.append(", number=");
    builder.append(number);
     builder.append(", description=");
    builder.append(description);
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}


}
```

Incident1.java

package com.asn.model;

```
  public class incident1 {

private String u_task_incident_service_ci;
private String priority;

public incident1(String u_task_incident_service_ci, String priority) {

    super();

   if (u_task_incident_service_ci.equals("A"))
{ String Team= "A";
this.u_task_incident_service_ci = Team;}
 else
    this.u_task_incident_service_ci = u_task_incident_service_ci;

   if (priority.equals("1"))
 { String priority1 = "P1";
 this.priority = priority1;}
else
if (priority.equals("3"))
{ String priority3 = "P3";
this.priority = priority3;}
else
    this.priority = priority;
}
public String getu_task_incident_service_ci() {
    return u_task_incident_service_ci;
}
public void setu_task_incident_service_ci(String u_task_incident_service_ci) {

    this.u_task_incident_service_ci = u_task_incident_service_ci;
}
public String getpriority() {
    return priority;
}
public void setpriority(String priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((u_task_incident_service_ci == null) ? 0 : u_task_incident_service_ci.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((priority == null) ? 0 : priority.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    incident1 other = (incident1) obj;
    if (u_task_incident_service_ci == null) {
        if (other.u_task_incident_service_ci != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!u_task_incident_service_ci.equals(other.u_task_incident_service_ci))
        return false;
    if (priority == null) {
        if (other.priority != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!priority.equals(other.priority))
        return false;
    return true;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("incident1 [u_task_incident_service_ci=");
    builder.append(u_task_incident_service_ci);
    builder.append(", priority=");
    builder.append(priority);
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}


 }
```

Comment: I just pass the code it looks like so long, oh well.

Comment: but it is complete working code :(

Answer (score 0):

This code is rather ... peculiar. Looking at one method:

```
private static String 
getNumOfu_task_incident_service_cis(String u_task_incident_service_ci,
                                    List<String> prioritys,
                                    Map<incident1, Integer> count) {
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 for (String v : prioritys) {
     Integer cnt = count.get(new incident1(u_task_incident_service_ci, v));
     if (cnt == null) {
     cnt = 0;
     }
 }
 return builder.toString();
 }
```

Several "count" values are obtained from the Map, but the StringBuilder happily remains unchanged; the method always returns "".

Another method:

```
private static String 
getCountu_task_incident_service_cis1( ..., String number,... ){
       //...
       if ( v == "P1") {
     Integer cnt1 = count1.get(new incident200(u_task_incident_service_ci, v,number,description));
     if (cnt1 == null) {
         cnt1 = 0;
     } else
         if (cnt1 != 0){
         cnt1 = 1;
         //...
      return number;
}
```

Here, `cnt1` is set to 0 or 1,  but not used later on within the same if statement. And the return value is `number`, a String parameter. So - what's the point?

```
public incident200(String u_task_incident_service_ci,
                   String priority, String number,String description ) {
    super();
    if (u_task_incident_service_ci.equals("A")){
        String Team= "A";
        this.u_task_incident_service_ci = Team;}
    else
        this.u_task_incident_service_ci = u_task_incident_service_ci;
```

What's the purpose of this complication? A single statement would be sufficient:

```
this.u_task_incident_service_ci = u_task_incident_service_ci;
```

I regret that I can only point out why this code may be difficult to understand. Cleaning up the code might be a good start towards finding the bug.

**Later**

If method `getCountu_task_incident_service_cis1` should send emails, it does so for priorities P1 and P2 only:

```
for (String v : prioritys1) {
    if ( v == "P1") {
        // ...
    } else
    if ( v == "P2") {
            //...
        }
 }
```

Moreover, method `run` contains

```
for (String v2 : prioritys1  ) 
    if (v2 =="P1" ){
        // some code...
    }
}
```

Do you expect that any other priority is ever sent?

Comment: Hi i have used above two methods for other purpose for getting the count of priortys..

Comment: Return a "count", which normally is an integer, as a String? And if it does return something, why not leave it rather than obfuscate it?

Comment: See some results of trying to understand this rather messy code.